# Allure: Parameter annotation

Tags: parameters, allure

I have a question concerning Allure's parameter support. In the example at https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Parameters you annotated the method parameter with @Parameter. Unfortunately ru.yandex.qatools.allure.annotations.Parameter is only allowed to be annotated at fields. The TestNG Parameter annotation has field and method as target. So which Parameter annotation do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Allure 1.4.11, the possibilty to annotate parameters was added later on. After updating to 1.4.14 it works as expected.